# Unsigned Long Long Won't Go Beyond The 93th Fibonacci Number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, fibonacci

Here's the code I wrote for finding the n-th Fibonacci number:

```
unsigned long long fib(int n)
{
    unsigned long long u = 1, v = 1, t;

    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        t = u + v;
        u = v;
        v = t;
    }

    return v;
}
```

While the algorithm runs pretty quickly, the output starts to freak out when n>93. I think/know it's because of the unsigned long long's 64bit size. I'm new to C++ but are there ways of getting around this so I can get the answer of something like fib(9999)?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I was surprised that Fibonacci numbers grew quickly enough that F(94) > ~2^63.

Comment: Errr... how can this code work without braces for the `for` loop?

Comment: @Everyone Sorry I made some mistakes inputting the code. This is just error in transcribing though. fib(94) still gives me some Frankenstein number...

Comment: @John Feminella: The Fibonacci sequence grows exponentially. Binet's Formala says F(n) = (phi^n - (-1/phi)^n) / sqrt(5), where phi = (sqrt(5)+1)/2.

Comment: Fibbonacci[x] behaves very similar to Exp[x/2]

Comment: @Derek: I'm aware of that, but I'm still surprised! Lots of real-world things that grow exponentially don't get very big quickly. As a simple example, consider compound interest. If you invest $10,000 at 10% annual interest in the stock market, even at t = 94 years you still don't have anywhere close to 2^64 (although you do have ~$80 million).

Comment: @John Ferminella, Just to be rigorous, I used unsigned long long so the maximum value goes all the way up to 2^64. Anyway, fib(94)> 2^64. That's some growth!

Comment: Agreed. fib(94) > 2^64.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://gmplib.org/

> GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a regular interface.
>
> The main target applications for GMP are cryptography applications and research, Internet security applications, algebra systems, computational algebra research, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the fast and concise answer!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208693/why-was-my-answer-linking-to-my-google-code-project-deleted?lq=1 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice

Answer (score 4):

Use a bigint library. There are plenty around the web (e.g., [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/) and [here](http://gmplib.org/)) or roll your own.

EDIT: Rolling your own is much more difficult than I expected. The arithmetic isn't the hard part; it's printing out the result in decimal form.

Comment: What do you mean "roll" your own? Write my own bigint?

Comment: @Leebuntu Yes, that's exactly what he means

Comment: @Leebuntu: Yes. For the purpose at hand, you only need `operator+`, which is pretty easy to code up with respect to a `vector<unsigned>` representing an arbitrarily large integer. (Of course, you would need `operator<<` to write out the answer.)

Comment: The last digit is just the number mod 10. Divide by 10 and repeat for the next-last number, and so on.  But using gmp is a much better idea than rolling your own!

Comment: @PaulCrowley: At the time, I was probably wondering if there was a way to avoid division and print left to right in O(n) time (n = digits).