# Getting factorial of a large number

Tags: java, algorithm, math, factorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate the factorial of an arbitrarily large number, showing all the digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966077/calculate-the-factorial-of-an-arbitrarily-large-number-showing-all-the-digits)

This question might be asked thousand times here. I am repeating my question with a modification. I want to calculate factorial of a large number (`max range of the number=10^6`). Generally we uses a `for` loop from `i=1` to `i=number` and every time multiplying the old value to the new value. This is fine for small numbers but what if i have a large number? The range of `for` loop is increased now. Java primitive data type `int`, `long` can't handle the resultant large number. They simply overflows. Although i knew about `BigInteger` class, which can handle this large output but still `for` loop is not suiting better here for me. Can somebody please suggest me any tick, any hack to calculate factorial of a number? Below is the simple program which works fine for small number-

```
public long getFactorial(long number) {
    long factorial = 1;
    for (long i = 1; i <= number; ++i) {
        factorial *= i;
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

Comment: `1000000!` is `12,815,519` digits long. You're gonna need a "real" bignum library to handle that.

Comment: There are linkedlist/stack based solutions to achieve this. Such as [this](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~allen/S12/NOTES/BigFactorial.pdf) one

Comment: @Ravi Joshi: perhaps you should clarify whether you need a precise (BigInteger) answer, or whether an approximation would do.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: I need precise answer. Because this resultant value will be used next.

Comment: Correction to my first comment: It's `5,565,709`
 digits. I forgot to divide by `log(10)`. But the point still holds: You need a "real" bignum library with sub-quadratic multiplication - something that Java's BigInteger currently does not have

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125872/unsigned-long-long-wont-go-beyond-the-93th-fibonacci-number

Comment: I seriously doubt that you need that number.  You might think you do, but you're likely to be wrong.  And that's as naive a factorial implementation as you could wish for.  No ln(gamma), no memoization.  You won't get far with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Understand that the value is in the range of 10<sup>5565708</sup>.  It's going to take up about two megabytes of space, all by itself.

That said, [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [`BigIntegerMath.factorial(int)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html#factorial-int-) is good enough to handle it, and more importantly, it's actually been optimized for large factorials -- it'll do *significantly* better than a straightforward `for` loop.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava...and wrote much of `BigIntegerMath.factorial` myself.)

That said, I wouldn't exactly call it fast -- my benchmarks indicate an average of 414ms for a factorial in that range -- but there isn't going to be a truly fast solution, not without extremely heavy-duty bignum libraries, and I wouldn't expect even those to be *significantly* faster.

That's if you need the exact value.  If you can settle for the logarithm, then yeah, either use Apache's `logGamma(n+1)` to get `ln(n!)`, or approximate it yourself:

```
double logFactorial = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  logFactorial += Math.log(i);
}
```

Some rounding error will probably accumulate, but it's supposed to be an approximation anyway.

Comment: Cool... But i have to first look over the source code of `factorial` method of `Guava`. I should know the logic. Thank you.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: Do you mean 414 ms for `factorial(1_000_000)`, really? On my computer it takes over 200 seconds. I doubt your computer is 500 times faster than mine. Any explanation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an approximation function called [Stirling's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) for such large values of n.

You can refer to my answer here for more details:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134968/number-of-combinations/134972#134972

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**Gamma function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Gamma(i + 1) = i!

[org.apache.commons.math.special](https://commons.apache.org/math/) provides it for Java.

What people typically do is to calculate log(Gamma(i+1)) and then work in log-space (multiplications become additions, etc.).

Here are some other methods to calculate the factorial quickly: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Comment: I didn't hear about `Gamma` function for calculating factorial. Can you please elaborate it in detail with an example. Thank you.

Comment: The result won't fit into a `double`.  It'll just be `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.  Unless the OP is willing to settle for the logarithm of the factorial, this won't be much help.

Comment: @RaviJoshi check again. See the first equation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The log of the factorial can be easily stored in a double.

Comment: Yes, the log can be stored, but the OP didn't indicate that he was interested in the log.  I see you've since added some explanation as to how to work with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

You use `BigInteger` for `factorial`, and you still only need a `long` for `i`, the loop variable.  `i` only has to go up to 1000000.  What's the problem?

Comment: Have you analyzed the complexity of this? I'd say it's `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Mysticial: the question is about how to accomplish it, he was concerned about the limits of the for loop.  But it isn't a problem.  I'm not sure why you are bringing the time complexity into it.

Comment: I'm saying that it's gonna be impractical to go to any large `i` because the complexity is `O(n^2)`. Java's BigInteger doesn't have the right algorithm to bring it down to quasi-linear.

Comment: The length of the _result_ is going to be `O(n log n)`, and `BigInteger` uses a quadratic multiplication algorithm.  I think it might be _worse_ than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: If you do it by bottom-up multiplication, it'll be `O(n^2 log(n))` - regardless of the multiplication algorithm. To go sub-quadratic, you need sub-quadratic multiplication combined with some sort of product balancing technique.

Comment: The key to getting a faster factorial is not to focus on how to multiply, but on what to multiply.  For example, here's a Python implementation:  http://en.literateprograms.org/Factorials_with_prime_factorization_%28Python%29   On my machine, I got 10**6! in 44 seconds.